# Capturing console output in node.js with out editing server code

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, shell, console

First stackoverflow question!  I am trying to capture all console.log() output from a node.js server.  Assume I am on a linux machine and **I cannot edit the server's code**, (project leader's request).  I can, however change how I start the server (node --debug server.js) and I can attach shell scripts.  My intent is to pipe the console output into another socket.io server.

I am thinking the only obvious solutions are to either write a linux command to pipe output of the server into something or node.js has a tricky --debug method to output the information.

End result, I want to be able to run the server and pipe the console output to a API testing server.  That way, a tester would be able to see, streaming, the output of the server in correlation to the response JSON objects from the API end points.

Thanks, I would love to hear your solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered over IRC, if anyone's interested:

```
<shesek> patrickm, can't you just pipe the output to another script?
<shesek> node server.js | node send-logs-to-somewhere.js
<shesek> patrickm, in send-logs-to-somewhere.js, you can just read from process.stdin
<patrickm> :)
<patrickm> thats easy
```

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know that was possible. `send-logs-to-somewhere.js` just keeps listening for input?

Comment: yea it works beautifully.  i open a socket.io connection, open stdin, let the magic happen.